# How does IE11 decode the Audio stream, and it doesn't support Web-Audio-API?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, html5-audio, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

Now I use Audio-API to decode the audio stream, which can play sounds in other browsers, but IE11 can't be implemented. Does Javascript have other methods or need to use ActionScript3?

Answer (score 1):

No, IE11 doesn't have Web Audio API support (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) but there's a [Howler](https://howlerjs.com/) library that might help you. I wouldn't rely on AS3 because people are not installing Flash Player and are relying Pepper API in Chrome.

Comment: This is a great library, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be able to decode the audio stream.